# Applescript+Shell Compare list of folders to list of files and move files into subfolders

Tags: bash, shell, applescript

I'm trying to create an applescript that will run the bash script below. Moving any file named temp_m to a folder with a matching name. Screenshots provided for reference. The benefit of the applescript being easy for the user to choose the "loose images" (source) folder and the build out (archive) folder. They will often exist in different locations, sometimes on a server/share.

E.G. from

[image]

to

[image]

```
set myFolder to (choose folder)
set pFolder to POSIX path of myFolder
set folderNames to paragraphs of (do shell script "

PARENTDIRECTORY="pFolder"
find . -name "*.jpg" | while read file
do
   temp_m=$(basename "$file" .jpg)
   look=$(echo "$PARENTDIRECTORY/*/*${temp_m}" | sed 's/ /\\ /g') #I need to match all     subfolders in this parent folder that have the same name as temp_m name
   look=$(eval echo $look)
   if [ -f "$look" ]
   then
       todir="${look%/*}"
       echo mv "${temp_m}.jpg" ${todir}/ # echo action to perform - after testing remove echo
   else
       echo "No unique match for $file ($look)"
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You might just use a shell command like this:

`shopt -s nullglob;for f in ~/Pictures/loose\ files/*.jpg;do f2=${f##*/};d=~/Pictures/*/*/*/*/${f2%_*};[[ $d ]]&&echo mv "$f" $d;done`

`shopt -s nullglob` makes filename patterns that don't match any files expand to an empty string. `${f##*/}` removes the longest `*/` pattern from the start of `f` and `${f2%_*}` removes the shortest `_*` pattern from the end of `f2`. `[[ $d ]]` is equivalent to `[[ -n $d ]]`, or it tests if `$d` is set and not set to an empty string.

If the target folders can be at different nesting levels, you can use `find`:

`for f in ~/Pictures/loose\ files/*.jpg;do f2=${f##*/};d=$(find ~/Pictures -type d -name ${f2%_*});[[ $d ]]&&echo mv "$f" $d;done`

Comment: +1 for concision, though you probably want to use `[[ -d $d ]]` to ensure that only a directory matched; also, I suggest you double-quote `$d` in the `mv` command.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your bash code; here's a cleaned-up version, which tries what I *think* you're trying to do, based on your description and the screenshots:

```bsh
# Set the source and target [root] dir as POSIX paths.
# Do NOT quote spaces here - this will be done below - but
# note that, if applicable, you must use the explicit home-directory
# path rather than '~'.
tell application "System Events"
  set SOURCEDIRECTORY to "."
  # Example: Set to ~/Pictures/Archive
  set PARENTDIRECTORY to POSIX path of home folder & "/Pictures/Archive"
end tell

# Set the level in the target subdirectory hierarchy at which the 
# specific target directories are located.
set SUBDIRLEVEL to 4

do shell script "
SUBDIRLEVEL=" & SUBDIRLEVEL & "
SOURCEDIRECTORY=" & quoted form of SOURCEDIRECTORY & "
PARENTDIRECTORY=" & quoted form of PARENTDIRECTORY & "

find \"$SOURCEDIRECTORY\" -type f -name \"*.jpg\" | while read file; do

  # Determine the subdir name prefix - everything before
  # the first \"_\" - with the extension stripped in any event.
  temp_m=$(cut -d '_' -f 1  <<<\"$(basename \"$file\" .jpg)\")

  # At the specified subdir level, find subdirs. of \"$PARENTDIRECTORY\"
  # whose name matches the prefix.
  matches=$(find \"$PARENTDIRECTORY\" \\
           -mindepth $SUBDIRLEVEL -maxdepth $SUBDIRLEVEL \\
           -type d -name \"${temp_m}\")

  # Expected: exactly 1 match.
  # Note: As long as only 1 level of subdirs is matched, there is 
  #          no strict need to test for *more* than 1 match.
  if [[ -n $matches && $(wc -l <<<\"$matches\") -eq 1 ]]; then
    todir=$matches
    # echo action to perform - after testing, remove echo       
    echo mv \"$file\" \"${todir}/\" 
  else
    echo \"No unique match for $file ($temp_m)\"
  fi

done
"
```

Note:

- This code - as your original - is NOT designed to simply *list* folder names, so the `set folderNames to paragraphs of` before `do shell script` doesn't make sense.
- Subdirectories are matched only at the specified hierarchy level. If you need more flexibility, tweak the `-mindepth $SUBDIRLEVEL -maxdepth $SUBDIRLEVEL` options as needed (removing them would search across ALL levels).

Comment: Thank you, though I'm still having issues getting applescript to pass the parent directory var and run the shell script.

Comment: @user3305972: I've updated my post with the shell command properly escaped for passing to `do shell` script, plus a demonstration of how to pass variable values to the shell command. HTH.